# Applying styles to PyQt widgets from external stylesheet

Tags: python, macos, qt5, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I'm starting a new project from scratch and trying to put a few pieces together. I'm using PyQt5 and Python3.6.

I'm reading an external stylesheet, using this code:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qss="joe.qss"
with open(qss,"r") as fh:
    app.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
```

So far my qss file contains this:

```
QPushButton#blue {
    background-color: blue; 
    font: 57 13pt "Futura";
}
```

I read about setting the `objectName` property to the tag after the hashmark in the style definition, so I tried this:

```
configbutton.setObjectName("blue")
```

No luck. I swear I managed this once before when I was a super-n00b and it seemed really easy. I've been bashing away at this stuff for a little while now and can't recreate that little scrap of code. I've tried to read the official Qt documentation, but I have a hard time translating the C++ to Python. I know how to set the style using `setStyleSheet` and can do that all day long, but that makes for messy code if you want a complicated style.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works, it would be great to share your project in a zip, to check what the problem is.

Comment: What platform are you testing this on?

Comment: Here's a gist of my two files: https://gist.github.com/bundito/a994d08cc254b34e03d32ef74774b066

I'm running PyQt 5.9.2 and Python 3.6.3 on macOS High Sierra (10.13.1).

Comment: @Ditto. Your code works for me on linux using python 3.6.3, qt 5.9.3, and pyqt 5.9.2. I assume there must be a platform-specific bug, but I could not find anything on the [qt bug-tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/issues/?jql=).

Answer (score 0):

the code is correct, read stylesheet file and apply to all GUI, the '#blue' here is button objectName, make sure the button is exist with same objectName

**apply stylesheet to button with objectName 'blue'**

```
QPushButton#blue{
background-color: blue; 
font: 57 13pt "Futura";
}
```

**apply stylesheet to all buttons on the GUI**

```
QPushButton#pushButton {
   background-color: red; 
   font: 57 13pt "Futura";
}
```

**then**

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qss="style.qss"
with open(qss,"r") as fh:
    app.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
widget = MainWindow()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).